# what is the latest Microsoft command line C/C++ compiler?

Tags: command-line, compiler-construction

What is the latest Microsoft command line C/C++ compiler?

Is it now free, what does it cost?

Looking for a link for it?

Thanks in advance,
Kevin Waite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm...

1. download [VS2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express)
2. install
3. Launch VS2010 Command Line shell
4. invoke `cl.exe /?` and profit

Comment: cool . . . is this an "express" versions? or a full productional level C/C++ comannd line compliler?  -- thanks!!!!

Comment: The compiler is fully functional. The MFC libraries are not included. The "rest" is. You can still download the free platform SDK, DDK, etc. MSDN is free; Life is good